# Is there a way to access the COM object for Excel (or Word etc) using M language, Power Query?

Tags: excel, vba, com, powerbi, m

The goal here is to access the com object for an office application (Excel or Word), and call the function `Workbooks.Open()` (Excel) or `Documents.Open()` (Word), all of this by using the `M language`, `Power Query`, not macros.

I want the functionality to be in a `.xlsx file`, a non-macro-enabled document (preferably).
The expected behavior is the same as this vbs code:

```
Dim excel: Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

excel.Workbooks.Open("<path_to_the_file>")
```

or,

```
Dim word: Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

word.Documents.Open("<path_to_the_file>")
```

Thank you very much, all good ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Can you explain the next steps and why you're doing this, and why you can't use for example the power query load from Excel to get your data?

Comment: The vbs code presented is used to **open programmatically** a document. I know that the `Power Query` from Excel **was not** created to do this. This is part of a bigger research. I believe that there exists a way to access the `com object` using `M language`. The purpose **is not** to load data, but it is to access the `com`

Comment: How about running `system commands` from `Power Query`?